# Deployment error regarding translations when generating package version

Tags: deployment, package, translation

In a scratch org where the translation workbench is enabled, I added English as a supported language (the language for the organization is Japanese) and ran the command `sfdx force:source:pull`, which adds `force-app/main/default/translations/en_US.translation-meta.xml` to my project. However, when running package:version:create I get the following error:

`en_US: Not available for deploy for this organization`

Has anyone else encountered this error or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things you have to do:

1. enable Translations in your Scratch-Org-Def (I guess, you already did).
2. let package-version-create use this scratch org def (I guess, that you didn't)

So you scratch org def should looklike this:

```
{
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "language": "en_US",
  "features": [],
  "settings": {
    "languageSettings": {
      "enableTranslationWorkbench":  true,
      "enableEndUserLanguages": true
    }
  }
}
```

And your package-Version-create like this:

```
$ sfdx force:package:version:create  -f config/<your scratch-org-def>.json
```

Comment: Thanks! Like you said, it turns out I didn't specify the path to the definition file when creating the package version. Once I did that I was able to create it as intended. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the setting *orgPreferenceSettings.translation* does not do anything if other *pathAssistantSettings.pathAssistantEnabled* setting is present, no idea if this happens with any other setting, I am going to open a support case to inform about this.

```
{
    "orgName": "Org",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "language": "en_US",
    "features": [
        "PersonAccounts",
        "Entitlements",
        "MultiCurrency"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "translation": true
        },
        "entitlementSettings": {
            "enableEntitlements": true,
            "enableEntitlementVersioning":true
        },
        "pathAssistantSettings":{
            "pathAssistantEnabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

A possible workaround is to deploy an OrgPreferenceSettings.settings-meta.xml with that option enabled.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrgPreferenceSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <preferences>
        <settingName>Translation</settingName>
        <settingValue>true</settingValue>
    </preferences>
</OrgPreferenceSettings>
```